# Is there -any- way to disable/renable sessions at will in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

In the Web developer toolbar for Firefox, there's an option to turn on, and off sessions at will, this is very useful for testing purposes.

The toolbar for Chrome doesn't have it as an option and I'm unable to find anything online about being able to temporarily disable and enable a session without having to shut down/restart a browser and navigate back to a page and restart a session...

Does anyone have a way to obtain this behavior in Google chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not have session functionality built-in, but there are extensions that [provide this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?category=ext&q=session), arguably the best of which is [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko)—I swear by this one.

Comment: Thanks for the response - but that seems to just handle open tabs, etc. I meant something related to web development / 'cookie'-type session on/off toggle

Comment: Ah okay. I wasn’t sure which session you meant (in fact, I considered that you may have meant “session” in terms of a network connection). Hmm, I’m not sure about this. You could try [requesting it](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/).